# trivial group actions V.s trivial homomorphisms ?!

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

this question is related to the semidirect product of groups   ,

so let $H,K$ are groups.

suppose , $f:K \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism . 
so $H\rtimes_f K$ is a semidirect product .

the problem now is as follows ,
if i supposed that $f$ is the trivial homommorphism ,so $\forall k\in K, f(k)=1$

this guy , $f$ , can be extended to a nother function , say $g$ , whose codomain is $S_{|K|}$
and $g(k)=f(k)$ with no change with the domain .

so there is no change with the semedirect product , now , the definition of the product of the elements of the semidirect product  uses the  group action which is  defined using this homomorphism $g$, but $g$ is trivial  homomorphism as $f$ is the trivial homomorphism

so this group action from $K$ on $H $ is also trivial .

so for any\every $k\in K , h\in H $ we have $ k * h=f_k(h) = 1$ where * denotes operation of the the action and this is the trivial action.

but in Dummit and foote , it's defined that the trivial action is $\forall  k \in K , h\in H , k*h=h $

and they are not the same clearly ! what is wrong ? how can this trivial homomorphism afford  the group action like the text provide ? and where is my wrong ?

Comment: It seems like something is off here. $H \rtimes K$ comes from a homomorphism $f\colon K \to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ that "gives conjugation". There's some matter of conventions here but the upshot ought to be that in the new group, $khk^{-1}$ is the element $f(k)(h)$ of $H$. If $f$ is trivial then it isn't the case that multiplication by elements of $K$ is trivial [$K$ is supposed to be an honest subgroup of the new group, so this would be impossible if $K$ is non-trivial], but that they commute with elements of $H$.

Comment: @TTS Post that as an answer ;-)